# JDialog.isVisible() Not Executing on Event Dispatch Thread When it Should Be?

Tags: java, swing, event-dispatch-thread

I am building a JDialog on the EDT. As soon as I call pack() the JDialog's isVisible method is called several times. The first time it's called SwingUtilities.isEventDispatchThread() returns false. Why is that? Sample program follows.

```
public class EDTTest extends JDialog
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater( () -> {
            EDTTest  dialog  = new EDTTest();
            dialog.buildGUI();
        });
    }
    
    private void buildGUI()
    {
        JButton button  = new JButton( "Exit" );
        JPanel  panel   = new JPanel();
        
        button.addActionListener( e -> System.exit( 0 ) );
        panel.add( button );
        setContentPane( panel );
        System.out.println( "Packing" );
        pack();
        setVisible( true );
    }
    
    @Override
    public boolean isVisible()
    {
        System.out.println( SwingUtilities.isEventDispatchThread() );
        boolean isVis   = super.isVisible();
        return isVis;
    }
}
```

Comment: The only time I see it present `false` is when you close the dialog and seems to be part of the tear workflow, either of Swing or the JVM

Comment: Just try `if(!SwingUtilities.isEventDispatchThread()) Thread.dumpStack();`

Comment: @MadProgrammer I definitely see false immediately after executing pack(), and before pushing Close. I am using JDK 17 on Windows 11 Pro.

Comment: @Holger Thanks for the suggestion. I also printed out the thread name, which is AWT-Windows when isEventDispatchThread is false, and AWT-EventQueue-0 every other time. The stack trace starts with WToolkit.java (java.desktop/sun.awt.windows.WToolkit.run(WToolkit.java:365)).

Comment: @JackStraub Java 17.0.3.1 on MacOS - seems to be a platform specific issue

Comment: That’s an AWT toolkit specific thread, for processing native events.